# Why does my floating action button jumps to the top of the page when the app starts?

Tags: android, xml

I have currently a problem with a recycler view and a floating action button in my android app. The button always jumps to the right top of the page when I start the app.

The RecyclerView and the Button are inside a fragment. Currently I am using a ConstraintLayout to say the Button should always appear at the right end of the screen. However, I also tried it with a RelativeLayout and CoordinatorLayout with anchor and gravity attributes. In Android Studio, the layout shows it correct, with the button at the bottom right side of the screen. As soon as I start the app on my phone, it appears on the top right side of the screen...

Layout preview:

[image: Layout preview]

When I start the app on my phone:

[image: Screen on my phone]

Here's my Code I am using right now for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_bucketlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_bucketList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_addToBucketList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: are you sure your fragment consume full space in activity.

Comment: @Killer how do I see that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the recyclerview and fab button within a CoordinatorLayout.

The attribute `app:layout_anchorGravity:` will specify how an object should be positioned relative to an anchor, on both the X and Y axes, within its parent’s bounds.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  android:id="@+id/fragment_bucketlist"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_bucketList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/android_floating_action_button_icon"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/rv_bucketList"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:borderWidth="1dp"
    app:elevation="10dp" />

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a RelativeLayout. There was a problem that the Floating Action Button always showed up on the bottom edge and "stucked" at the bottom navigation bar (HUAWEI devices). The attribute app:useCompatPadding="true" solved the issue.

Here is the updated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/fragment_bucketlist"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_bucketList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_addToBucketList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```